# Add value of key that will be pushed to an array Angular

Tags: html, angularjs

The value inside the input and textarea should be pushed the entire JavaScript part works, but how can I bind the ng-model so that Angular will pick up the value of entered information and push that into an array. Anyone an idea how to do that in HTML.

```js
angular.module("forum-page", ["myApp"])
 .controller("Forum", function($scope) {
  $scope.comments = [
   {
   "name": "Kevin", 
   "comment": "Wat een mooi toestel vandaag ontvangen, zeer blij met mijn bestelling :)", 
   "country": "Nederland"
   }, 
   {
   "name": "Jason", 
   "comment": "What a great phone I received from Meizu, will surely come back to buy again in the future", 
   "country": "USA"
   }, 
   {
   "name": "姚宣辰", 
   "comment": "這個手機很標亮， 下次也會買魅族智能手機", 
   "country": "中国"
   }, 
  ];

 $scope.addComment = function() {
  $scope.comments.push({ "name": $scope.name, "comment": $scope.comment, "country": $scope.country});

  var dataObj = {
   name: $scope.name, 
   comment: $scope.comment, 
   country: $scope.country
  }; 

  $scope.dataObj = dataObj;

  res.error(function(data, status, header, config) {
   alert("failure message: " + JSON.stringify({data: data}));
  });

  $scope.name = "";
  $scope.comment = "";
  $scope.country = "";
 };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="comment-box-name" ng-model="{{dataObj.name}}"/>
<input type="text" class="comment-box-comment" ng-model="{{dataObj.comment}}"/>
<textarea type="text" class="comment-box-country" ng-model="{{dataObj.country}}"></textarea>


<button ng-click="addComment()">Place comment</button>
```

Comment: Did you checked my answer ?

Comment: Yes have played around with, but nothing works

Comment: You can see the demo it is working as per your requirement

Comment: Maybe I did not communicate clearly, but now added rest of the codes. The value should be pushed to the array, but that did not happen.

Comment: I saw your code my answer will work. please try again.

Comment: Sorry not working ....

Comment: I updated the demo fiddle in my answer please check now.

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot do that if you want that kind of automation in the template. In order to do that kind of action you need to place that action inside your click event listener which acts as the **send** button.

```
$scope.addComment = function () {
    // Add validations before proceeding
    theArray.push(dataObj);
}
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

**Some changes needed in your code :**

**1.** remove `{{}}` from the `ng-model` value.

use `dataObj.name,dataObj.comment,dataObj.country` instead of `{{dataObj.name}},{{dataObj.comment}},{{dataObj.country}}`

**2.** use `$scope` object instead of `var` to initialize the object to perform the two way data binding.

```
$scope.dataObj = {
  name: $scope.name, 
  comment: $scope.comment, 
  country: $scope.country
};
```

## [Demo!](http://jsfiddle.net/21jn5awf/1/)

Comment: When I click on the button, the comment should be dropped on the webpage. That is not happen here......

Comment: the comment should be dropped on the webpage ? means .. you want to display the comments array data in the UI ?

Comment: $scope.comments are shown on the webpage already, the values of input and texarea should be push behind them. Just like Stack Overflow, when you push on the add comment button.

Comment: I can not understand bro..check my answer fiddle it is working as per your requirement. It push the input data into an comments array as an object.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40615945/7087446 this is the right answer I was looking for